# Posts attribution with iOS share sheet

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, dialog, share

According to the *share-dialogs-ios-sdk* doc: `facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-dialogs-ios-sdk`

"Posts from the share sheet are attributed to iOS by default; contact Facebook to correctly configure attribution for your app"

I'd like to configure the attribution, please let me know how.

Comment: Did you ever find out who to contact at Facebook to do this?

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you "contact Facebook to correctly configure attribution for your app".